# Why I am not able to change layout with button in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am not able to change layout when clicking on the button. Actually, I always use this code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == imageButtonOrders) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Order.class)); }
```

Now, I want to use this function in my `ListView`. But when I use it I am getting an error. How can I fix it?

**SwipeListAdapterP.java**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_items, null);

    TextView pk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pk);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView point = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.point);
    ImageButton imageButtonDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDelete);
    ImageButton imageButtonUpdate = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonUpdate);

    ProductItems m = productList.get(position);

    pk.setText(String.valueOf(m.getPk()));
    name.setText(String.valueOf(m.getName()));
    point.setText(String.valueOf(m.getPoint()));

    imageButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Order.class));
    }});
```

Comment: Please provide more information about error.

Answer (score 0):

You need your parent activity `context` to start Activity from your Adapter class.

instead of:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(this, Order.class));
```

use:

```
 activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Order.class));
```

where `activity` is the `Activity` context your are passing to your Adapter class

Comment: I tried this but i take error from "startActivity".

Comment: @AlpYuktug if the answer helps..mark it as correct by clicking the Tick sign on left of the answer..thankx

Answer (score 0):

**try OnClick this way**

//cast imageButtonOrders by `findViewById()`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == imageButtonOrders) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Order.class));
     }
```

**in Adapter You need to Initialize `Context` with Activity reference and pass that `Context` on `Intent`**

```
imageButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(`Context`, Order.class));
    }});
```